# Air Quality of a Small Server Room

Tags: untagged

I work in a small office and sit in a small server room working on a computer making telephone calls.  After 2 hours I feel like I'm soffocating.  What is the effect of the computer equipment and servers on the air quality of a room approximately 10 feet by 6 feet?

Comment: You're sat *next* to the server rack? That cannot be a healthy working enviroment - the noise and temperature is probably not comfortable and the air con is also probably recycling the air instead of drawing fresh air in. I'd talk to your companies Health and Safety personnell.

Comment: server rack an a room 1.8 x 1.2 meters - that means pretty much he works STANDING and working ON THE RACK ;)

Comment: This is off topic. That said, there are laws in most countries that prohibit this kind of thing for various reasons. Contact your HR department or local labor authority for more details.

Answer (score 3):

All the servers do is warm the air.  They shouldn't add any contaminants.  The warm air can certainly make the room feel like it is losing oxygen, but assuming there is some reasonable circulation, if not A/C, that likely isn't an issue, either.

All that said, you need to talk to your manager and help them find a better place for you to work.  It is disrespectful to you.

Comment: Correction on room size.  It is probably 10 feet by 6feet.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: Actually some people do react to offgassing from plastics/etc. when they're warmed. Even being near printers and copiers have similar effects. A/C units can also harbor mold and such as well, and the air gets recirculated instead of bringing in fresh air. It's not all that healthy, but shouldn't (ordinarily) be toxic for most people. At least not in long-term constant exposure.

Comment: There's a reason that some engineers who can name what component just blew out on a circuit board by the smell wafting in the room aren't always "right" in the head...

Answer (score -1):

Noone can answer that - depends a lot on air conditioning anyway.

THAT SAID: Hwo loud is it? I can not imagine sitting in a server room.

Also - 6 feet x 4 feet? That is waht? 1.2 x 1.8 meters? You livei n a slave camp?

This is ahrdly enough to put a DESK there, with some computers on top... let me formulate it like that:

I would not care about air quality, the room is ILLEGAL AS OFFICE TO START WITH. At least where I live.

Comment: T add: This is a VERY small room. FOrge the servers for a moment - YOU use up the air. Without good circulation natuarlly the oxigen gets bad. Even without servers. THis is jsut a SMALL room with a person breathing.